# Constraining the least squares fitting in python

Tags: python, numpy, linear-algebra, mathematical-optimization, least-squares

I want to solve the following in a least-squares sense:

```
H = dot(A, B) + dot(A.conj(), C)
```

where the complex matrices `H`, `B` and `C` are known. The remaining complex matrix `A` (with its complex conjugate) is being searched.

I tried computing it with the (Python) numpy function:

```
x, res, r, singval = np.linalg.lstsq(np.vstack((B, C)), H)
```

However the results are not in a shape that I want( --> `array((A, A.conj())`).

How can I solve this?

Comment: if you would like to do constraint nonlinear least squares look at lmfit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way I found is separating the value of `A` into real and imaginary part:

```
A = U + 1j*V
```

therefore:

```
H = dot(U, B+C) + 1j*dot(V, B-C)
```

and with the use of `scipy.optimize.lstsqr`, the model is defined as:

```
def model(B, C, UV):
    U = UV[:len(UV)//2]
    V = UV[len(UV)//2:]
    H = np.dot(U, B+C) + 1j*np.dot(V, B+C)
    return H.view(float)
```

and the residuals as:

```
def residuals(params, B, C, H):
    UV = params
    diff = model(B, C, UV) - H.view(float)
    return diff.flatten()
```

and the result is obtained as follows:

```
params, cov = optimize.leastsq(residuals, x0 = np.ones(len(UV), dtype = float), 
                               args=(B, C, H))
```